# Can't equate one column in an Access record with another column in the same record

Tags: ms-access, combobox, null, dlookup

I am working with Access version MS 365 Apps for enterprise (desktop version).

When I try to get a specific field value out of my table, I instead get the equivalent to an empty or null result.

I'm in the debug phase. I provide an abreviated example here so you can see the field is reading as Null (i.e., it is saying that my called combo box value is the ID value (it is supposed to be a name) and that my table has no entry in the "Initials" field, which is associated with that record):

[Selected value is the ID number, not the LastName field value, and there seems to be no other fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIeYY.png)

In my table "People", with the autogenerated ID included as a column, I have only 4 columns (fields) in my table:

[Design View]

```
 ID - AutoNumber
 LastName - Long Text
 Type - Long Text
 Initials - Long Text
```

My table has only 9 entries and looks like this:

[Datasheet View]

| ID | LastName | Type | Initials |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LastName1 | Ms1 | LNI1 |
|  | ... |  |  |
| 9 | LastName9 | Dr9 | LNI9 |

I am creating panels using the table "People".

In a userform, I have unbound combo boxes as input on LastName: cmbo_LastName1 (Row Source "People", Row Source Type "Table/Query", Bound Column "1"), cmbo_LastName2 (same), cmbo_LastName3 (same).

In form view, when I use the combo boxes, I see the last names as being displayed when selected (so I know it is dipping correctly into my table). The ID value is not displayed.

I am also calling the "Initials" value from the "People" table into my code because my output (report) will include that information:

```
Dim selectedName As Variant
Dim P1Initials As Variant

' Get the selected name from the combo box
selectedName = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Value

' Lookup to get the corresponding initials
P1Initials = DLookup("Initials", "People", "LastName = '" & selectedName & "'")

' Check for Null before assigning
If Not IsNull(P1Initials) Then
    ' Convert to String if not Null
    P1Initials = CStr(P1Initials)
Else
    ' Handle the case when no matching record is found
    P1Initials = "N/A"
End If

' At this debug stage, output the result
MsgBox "Selected Name: " & selectedName & vbCrLf & _
       "Corresponding Initials: " & P1Initials
```

The above code gave me a Selected Name as the ID number, rather than the LastName value. I could only get the LastName value by forcing the code: "selectedName = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Column(1)" -- I'm unclear why it wasn't on column 2: i.e., column 1 should be ID, which would make LastName column 2.

When I tried, instead, P1Initials = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Column(3)" (thinking to be clever), that resulted in a null error (also on column 2 and column 4).

I have to be missing something simple.

I would have thought it would be easy to collect the value from one column in a record and equate it and spit out the value from another column in the same record, without directly having to collect the information in a combo box from the user.

I do not want to have a second combo box on "Initials" (because I'm actually going to be doing more with the information in the table "People" and I don't want to have to collect every little piece of information found in the table).

I have tried

1. repairing the database
2. recreating the table
3. making sure the first column width is 0
4. making sure the column count is 4

---

Edit
In the end, learning that ID was column indexed as 0, I ended up brute forcing the issue:

```
NamePanel1 = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Column(1)                    NamePanel2 = Me.cmbo_LastName2.Column(1)
NamePanel3 = Me.cmbo_LastName3.Column(1)
P1Initials = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Column(3)
P2Initials = Me.cmbo_LastName2.Column(3)
P3Initials = Me.cmbo_LastName.Column(3)
```

I never found out why the LastName value kept reverting back to ID.

Comment: Column index begins with 0 so column 1 is index 0. You should be searching on ID instead of name. Value of combobox should be ID if it is actually in first column and BoundColumn is 1. Since you don't specify fields in the RowSource, are you sure ID is in first column? What will you do if you have multiple people with same last name?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 100% ID is in the first column and, in datasheet view, my table looks like this:ID LastName Type Initials
1 LastName1 Ms1 LNI1
...  
9 LastName9 Dr9 LNI9

Comment: So what happens if you use: `selectedName = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Column(0)`? I think Variant defaults to string. Why not explicitly declare variable type? Use Nz() to handle possible Null `P1Initials = Nz(DLookup(...), 0)`

Comment: Time: Thanks for the comment.  This is my first serious foray into Access (but I know some VBA). I do not want to search on ID. My combo box is on LastName and that is what I want to display (not the ID, which for the user is uniformative). I am 100% that ID is in the first column and, in datasheet view, my table looks like this:ID LastName Type Initials
1 LastName1 Ms1 LNI1
...  
9 LastName9 Dr9 LNI9. I can't find the Column Index property, but TY for telling me that: which means that "Initials" is column index 3, but I still get a null on that and in my code I am specifying column names.

Comment: You have DLookup set to use name string and referencing Column(1) is correct method to retrieve name instead of combobox Value which is the ID. Still say should search on ID but show user whatever else you want. Nothing would change in combobox setup - just modify code.

Comment: I tried selectedName = Me.cmbo_Panel1Name_A.Value
selectedForcedN = Me.cmbo_Panel1Name_A.Column(1)
selectedID = Me.cmbo_Panel1Name_A.Column(0)
selectedForcedN = Me.cmbo_Panel1Name_A.Column(1)
P1InitialsForced = Me.cmbo_Panel1Name_A.Column(3) and got 4/4/NA/LN4 as a result.

Comment: My combo box is not supposed to be the ID. I have it directing to LastName, I have it displaying on LastName, and I am doing all code on LastName. ID is useless to me. I don't want ID. I want a Last Name displayed and their initials displayed, which is why I did an explicit DLookup call on "Initials" and "LastName", wherein the program is saying that "LastName" is ID and "Initials" doesn't exist.

Comment: oops: cmbo_Panel1Name = cmbo_LastName

Comment: I never suggested displaying ID. Users see name and initials but code would use ID. That would be best practice. If you don't want to use ID, why include it in combobox RowSource? Are you using ID as primary/foreign keys?

Comment: As far as I know, I didn't include ID in my combobox RowSource. I thought I was simply pulling from the "LastName" column (as that was what I wanted and that was what was displaying in the combo box when I selected the name). It wasn't until I received a null error on "Initials", that I found out ID was even being referenced. Obviously, somewhere, I must be using ID.

Comment: Your narrative says the combobox RowSource is `People` - the table name - that pulls ALL fields, in whatever order they are in table design.

Comment: That was so not my intent. This means I'll have to go back and re-inform myself as to how the database calls the data. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, learning that ID was column indexed as 0, I ended up brute forcing the issue:

```
NamePanel1 = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Column(1)
NamePanel2 = Me.cmbo_LastName2.Column(1)
NamePanel3 = Me.cmbo_LastName3.Column(1)
P1Initials = Me.cmbo_LastName1.Column(3)
P2Initials = Me.cmbo_LastName2.Column(3)
P3Initials = Me.cmbo_LastName.Column(3)
```

I never found out why the LastName value kept reverting back to ID.

Comment: Code was pulling ID because ID is Value of combobox.

Comment: Is that because of my source? My combo box was suposed to be pulling from, and on screen displayed from, the "LastName" column. The first I realized it was pulling from ID is when I began to debug. (edit on spelling)